# Rails 4: Server side processing for datatable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatable

I have a large data table and I am trying to use [DataTables](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) to organize the data. I want to use their server side processing for pagination, search, etc but I'm not sure how.  Their docs show:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "file.php" // or "ajax": "data.json"
});
```

but I am not sure what to pass as the file for my table?  How to I pass my entire table?  I'll happily give more information if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

When using server-side processing, DataTables sends a request to the path specified by that "ajax" property. For example, if you had a Book model, with a corresponding BooksController that responds properly to json requests, you'd have something like this assuming regular Rails resources routes:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "/books.json"
});
```

This would result in DataTables sending an Ajax request to your server, with search parameters as described here: http://datatables.net/manual/server-side

The "Configuration" section in the link above also has more information about setting the Ajax URL and settings.

Comment: When I do that I get the following: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Large)`.  Am I supposed to pass anything else?

Comment: @JeremyThomas, try setting the request type to POST as described in the link I gave you earlier. It'd probably be best to create a new action on your controller with a corresponding route at this point just for handling DataTables requests, just so it doesn't conflict with your other actions.

Comment: do you think you could point me in the right direction as to how to accomplish that?